# Is it possible to install different graphic cards and use multi-GPU in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, multi-gpu

I have a question.

Is it possible to install different graphic cards and use multi-GPU in pytorch?
Is there any other problem?

Ex>
Is the data parallel function of pytorch available in a combination of 3070 (1ea) + 3080 (1ea)?

Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is possible on the technical level, but it would be sub-optimal. The code that divides the load between the different GPUs assume they are the same. Having different GPUs will basically mean that you'll benefit according to the *minimal* performance of the GPUs you have.
For example, if you have a card with 1GB mem and another with 10GB you will only be able to work with batches suited for the 1GB card and have 9GB un-utilized on the second.

Comment: Thank you for answer.

The system works, but the 3080's performance matches (down-leveled) the 3070's.

Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: I suppose that will be the outcome. I never tried it, though.